# What would have been the signal that Pontiac would have given to attack in Fort Detroit?

Tags: colonial-america, native-americans

In the [Siege of Detroit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Fort_Detroit), Pontiac had 300 warriors but did not give the "signal" to attack (07 MAY 1763 before the actual siege started). I have found references that a [wampum belt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wampum) was involved in the signal; however, I've been unable to find what the signal was.  Knowing a bit about the cultural rituals, I suspect that the signal would have been subtle.

Does anyone have a reference for this signal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An article in a book on the  [*History of Macomb County, Michigan*](https://books.google.com/books?id=OT8XAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA48&dq=siege+detroit+pontiac+signal+to+attack&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjegqHYoLvwAhUXvp4KHdgrAC4Q6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=siege%20detroit%20pontiac%20signal%20to%20attack&f=false) from 1882 agrees with your connection to the wampum belt (emphasis mine):

> There is legend that a beautiful Chippewa girl well known to Gladwyn
> divulged to him scheme which the Indians had in view namely that the
> next day Pontiac come to the fort with sixty of his chiefs each armed
> with a gun cut short hidden under his blanket that Pontiac would
> demand a council deliver a speech offer a peace belt of wampum ***holding
> it in a reversed position as the signal for attack***; that the chiefs
> sitting upon the ground would then spring up and fire upon the
> officers and the Indians out in the streets would next fall upon the
> garrison and kill every Englishman but spare all the French

We can get a little more information about this belt from the [*History of the Indian Tribes of the United States*](https://books.google.com/books?id=FDj9JUtPtDEC&pg=PA244&dq=schoolcraft%20history%20indians%20pontiac%20green%20wampum%20belt&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8v5qdkL_wAhXK454KHc-gBuYQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=schoolcraft%20history%20indians%20pontiac%20green%20wampum%20belt&f=false), by [Henry Schoolcraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Schoolcraft). On pg. 244 Schoolcraft discusses this (emphasis mine):

> But an attack was not his first move he aimed to take the fort by a
> laid plot which was in effect to visit the commandant at his quarters
> accompanied a limited number of assassins bearing concealed weapons to
> smoke with him the of peace and to present him with a formal address
> which was to be accompanied by a belt of wampum the most solemn and
> honored custom in Indian diplomacy This was worked on ***one side with
> white and on the other with green beads*** finished his speech with the
> white side turned towards his auditor the ***reversal of it in his
> hands to the green side was to be the signal of attack***

Schoolcraft cites the *Pontiac Manuscript* as his source for information about the belt. This primary source is described at the [University of Michigan site](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/clementsead/umich-wcl-M-266nav?id=navbarbrowselink;view=text):

> The Robert Navarre Journal of the Pontiac Conspiracy is a manuscript
> transcription of the original French account of Pontiac's siege of
> Detroit in 1763. The journal describes in great detail affairs on both
> sides of the conflict between May 7 and July 31, 1763, providing an
> eyewitness account from within the fort, as well as intelligence,
> news, and rumors of Pontiac's activities.

Some digital copies of this source can be found [here](https://digitalcollections.detroitpubliclibrary.org/islandora/object/islandora%3A224146). (note this is *handwritten* and *in French*)

Another source which offers some insights into this event would be by [Francis Parkman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Parkman),  *[The conspiracy of Pontiac and the Indian War after the conquest of Canada](https://books.google.com/books?id=uo4-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA228&dq=pontiac%20siege%20schoolcraft%20wampum&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjlmYK5o7_wAhUC6Z4KHTZVCMkQ6AEwA3oECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=pontiac%20siege%20schoolcraft%20wampum&f=false)* . (He has an interesting note pointing out variations on the identity and fate of the 'heroine' of the story.)